# Accessing data inside a bag.tuple.bag.tuple

Tags: apache-pig

I have a dataset in a variable `data_1`

```
describe data_1; 
output:
group_2: {group: (age: int,phone: chararray),group_1: {(group: (age: int,phone: chararray,id: int),student_details: {(id: int,firstname: chararray,lastname: chararray,age: int,phone: chararray,city: chararray)})}}
```

and

```
DUMP data_1;
output:
(21,9848022330) {((21,9848022330,4),{(4,Preethi,Agarwal,21,9848022330,London)})}
(21,9848022337) {((21,9848022337,1),{(1,Rajiv,Reddy,21,9848022337,Paris)})}
(22,9848022338) {((22,9848022338,2),{(2,siddarth,Battacharya,22,9848022338,Kolkata)})}
(22,9848022339) {((22,9848022339,3),{(3,Rajesh,Khanna,22,9848022339,Delhi)})}
(23,9848022335) {((23,9848022335,6),{(6,Archana,Mishra,23,9848022335,Chennai)})}
(23,9848022336) {((23,9848022336,5),{(5,Trupthi,Mohanthy,23,9848022336,Bhuwaneshwar)})}
(24,9848022333) {((24,9848022333,7),{(7,Komal,Nayak,24,9848022333,trivendram)}),((24,9848022333,8),{(8,Bharathi,Nambiayar,24,9848022333,Chennai)})}
(111,9834534343)    {((111,9834534343,9),{(9,ABC,DEF,111,9834534343,Delhi1),(9,ABC,DEF,111,9834534343,Delhi2),(9,ABC,DEF,111,9834534343,Delhi3)})}
```

I want to remove the extra bag.tuple & only use the $1.$1 bag.

I am trying to accomplish that by using something like `group_2_normal = FOREACH data_1 GENERATE $0.age,$0.phone,$1.$1;` But i still am unable to remove the extra bag and tuple which surround the $1.$1 bag.

The output of the above foreach command is:

```
21  9848022330  {({(4,Preethi,Agarwal,21,9848022330,London)})}
21  9848022337  {({(1,Rajiv,Reddy,21,9848022337,Paris)})}
```

But desired output is:

```
21  9848022330  {(4,Preethi,Agarwal,21,9848022330,London)}
21  9848022337  {(1,Rajiv,Reddy,21,9848022337,Paris)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that using FLATTEN will help you. As far as you have only one row in the bag it will give you just what you want.

```
group_2_normal = FOREACH data_1 GENERATE $0.age,$0.phone,FLATTEN($1.$1);
```